# FXML FlowPane expanding to parent size

Tags: layout, javafx-8, fxml

I have an app with the following structure:

```
<GridPane>
    <columnConstraints>        
        <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="true" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints fillHeight="true" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <FlowPane fx:id="flwPictures" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" 
                GridPane.fillHeight="true" GridPane.fillWidth="true" 
                GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" >
            <padding>
                <Insets top="2.0" bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" />
            </padding>
            <children>              
            </children>
        </FlowPane>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

I need the `FlowPane` to fill the size of its parent container of the `GridPane`. The Nodes are added dynamically based on user selection. So far what I observe is that flow pane is not filling.

Comment: Which is happening: the flow pane is not filling the grid pane, or the grid pane is not filling its parent (whatever that is)? You only seem to have a single child node in the grid pane anyway: can't you remove the grid pane and just put the flow pane directly in the grid pane's parent?

Comment: Actually, I have another `ListView` on my `GridPane` left column. It is omitted for simplicity. The workflow is: when user clicks an item on `ListView`, then the app will load images on the `FlowPane` on the right column.